# Why doesn't Apple's SDK documentation cover UI*?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uitextfield

UIWebView, UIColor or UITextField for example have no entries in http://developer.apple.com/search.php or the documentation that comes with Xcode.  Are these documented somewhere?

Comment: All three of these have been added to the iPhone 3.0 SDK documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The iPhone OS document sets are definitely available in the documentation that comes with Xcode (iPhone SDK downloads). You maybe need to download it, though.

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090322-miff6sdtterr48pkbcjwh75pun.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090322-miff6sdtterr48pkbcjwh75pun.jpg)

Comment: It seems to be only in 3.0 as pointed out above.  2.2.1 doesn't have it.

Comment: Actually, if you look closely in the picture above the selected doc set is the 2.0, and I also double checked it here, UITextField is definitely included...

Comment: If I select the 2.0 it says "Last updated: 2008-06-16" at the end of the page and with 3.0 it says "Last updated: 2009-01-06"

Comment: just checked - these UI documentations have been available since 2.0

Comment: I see.  Where you have "iPhone OS Library", I had Xcode selected.  Works fine.  But why doesn't the website reflect those results?

Comment: That I do not know. My guess is that they don't want to publish it...yet

Answer (score 2):

This documentation is available on the iPhone developer center.

1. Goto [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com)
2. At the top, select Dev Centers and choose [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/)
3. open [iPhone Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html)
4. Click on [UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Frameworks/CocoaTouch/UIKit/index.html) on the left